# Disable sorting for a few cells in datatables jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

Simply I'm trying to make it ignore sorting if the cell has ?

this is my table:

```
ID | name  | supply
1  | John  | 12
2  | Kayle | ? 
3  | Tim   | 24
```

when you sort supply by asc

```
ID | name  | supply
1  | John  | 12
3  | Tim   | 24 
2  | Kayle | ?
```

when you sort supply by desc

```
ID | name  | supply
3  | Tim   | 24 
1  | John  | 12
2  | Kayle | ?
```

IS there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Absolute position sorting plug-in](https://datatables.net/blog/2016-12-22).

For example:

```
var nameType = $.fn.dataTable.absoluteOrder({
    value: '?', position: 'bottom'
});

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: 0, type: nameType }
    ]
});
```

You need to include `absolute.js` file in addition to DataTables CSS/JS files.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/u3skyadL/) for code and demonstration.